# Differentiability and Taylor series of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k ! \cdot\left(1+4^{k} x^{2}\right)}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, summation, taylor-expansion

Show, that $$g(x):=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k ! \cdot\left(1+4^{k} x^{2}\right)}$$ is infinitely often differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore prove that the Taylor Series of $g$ evaluated at zero diverges for all $x\neq 0$.

Expressing the Sum with the function $f:(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$ might be helpful. Also note $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k} x^{2 k}$ by the geometric series.

Comment: Did you mean to have $x^{2k}$ instead of $x^2$?

Comment: Inside the sum? No, I indeed meant $x^2$.